# Driving an electromagnet for 10 seconds without overheating the coil

Tags: lm317, electromagnet

I have the following issue that I would like to discuss.

I have an electromagnetic lock based on an electromagnet rated at 24V/44 ohms and a PSU at 24V. Basically, you apply a voltage at the coil and the magnet pulls a metal part that opens the door.

I need to keep the magnet energized for 8-10 seconds. The problem is that during this process the coil of the magnet is getting warm and if we want to power it again in a few seconds it will not have time to cool and the temperature rise might prove fatal.

I thought of driving the coil with 24V for 100ms and then lower the output to 5V or even below this to keep the temperature low. This way the magnet will have sufficient energy at the beginning and then the low voltage will be able to keep the metal part of the lock in the open state without the temperature getting high.

I am using an LM317 adjustable linear regulator.

I am thinking of applying 20V at the beginning for 100ms and then changing the feedback network to output 3V for the rest of the duration.

My question is if this is logical or if there is another approach I should consider.

Comment: Is the magnet providing the motive power for opening the door, or is it magnetically 'sticking' the door to a driven arm that's doing the opening? Draw the geometry of the problem. Your plan sounds like it will only work for the second option.

Comment: As above you need to provide more information, but you should experiment with your solenoid to find the minimum voltage that will actuate it, and also the minimum voltage and current once actuated that will hold it in place.  You may find the holding current can be reduced substantially.  You can also simply prevent it from being actuated too often in a variety of ways.  Best solutions will depend on your design and desired function.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using two-level voltage to drive solenoid is common practice to save energy and reduce heat. Actual voltage levels and delay time are subject of experimental tuning.

Don't forget to provide guarated path for self-induced current, for example a diode parallel to the coil.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you will provide a 24V PWM through a MOSFET driver, with a duty cycle corresponding to the minimum current needed for activation. This requires a MCU or some other smart driver though. Use a freewheel diode across the coil.

If the voltage regulator is placed close to the coil, then you might also want to swap out LM317 for something that won't melt through the floor. Like a proper switching regulator.